# Create an empty two dimensional array in Javascript, with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a matrix in Javascript, but one which has predefined keys for the X and Y axis.

For example I have the following keys

```
const x = [2,4,6,8]
const y = [10,20,40,60,80]
```

I found the following snippet which creates an empty two dimensional array with 4 rows and 5 columns

```
[...Array(4)].map(x=>Array(5).fill(0))
```

**I'm wondering if it's possible to create these arrays (objects), but using provided keys to go with it.**

So the end result would look like this.

```
{
    2 => {10 => 0, 20 => 0, 40 => 0, 60 => 0, 80 => 0}
    4 => {10 => 0, 20 => 0, 40 => 0, 60 => 0, 80 => 0}
    6 => {10 => 0, 20 => 0, 40 => 0, 60 => 0, 80 => 0}
    8 => {10 => 0, 20 => 0, 40 => 0, 60 => 0, 80 => 0}
}
```

Comment: why not take an object?

Comment: Well yes technically it would be an object since assoc array don't exist in js. I'll edit

Comment: Instead of `Array(5).fill(0)` try `Array.from( {length: 5}, () => 0 )`

Comment: Are you trying to create a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)? Apparently there are ready-made JS libraries to work with sparse matrices, e.g. [math.js](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/classes/sparsematrix.html).

Comment: @stop-cran No it's just to try and create an editable grid as a form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create the wanted objects by looping and reducing the data.

The callback of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes as first parameter the *accumulator*, here it is an object, and as second parameter the value of the iterating array.

As *startValue* for the `reduce`, it take an (kind of empty) object and usdes this object to add properties. To have this object (aka accumulator) ready for the next loop (and final result), it has to be returned.

```js
var x = [2, 4, 6, 8],
    y = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80],
    result = x.reduce((r, k) => {
        r[k] = y.reduce((q, l) => {
            q[l] = 0;
            return q;
        }, {});
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am getting a warning that "an arrow function should not return an assignment". Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 4):

You could `map` the `y` array to get the entries for a `row` object. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to get an object from the entries. Then `map` the `x` array to get the output object with a copy of each `row` object as value

```js
const x = [2, 4, 6, 8],
      y = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80],
      row = Object.fromEntries( y.map(v => [v, 0]) ),
      output = Object.fromEntries( x.map(key => [key, { ...row }]) )

console.log(output)
```

Cloning is required because modifying one of the rows will update the other values since they are all pointing to the same reference

Answer (score 3):

You can try following.

- Since you have same object repeated as child object, create it first.
- Now loop over parent keys and using spread or `Object.assign`, set it as object.

This way you have less number of iteration and code looks clean

```js
const x = [2,4,6,8]
const y = [10,20,40,60,80]

const innerObj = y.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[ item ] = 0;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = x.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[ item ] = { ...innerObj };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use forEach loop:

```js
const x = [2, 4, 6, 8]
const y = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80];

let results = {};
x.forEach(k => {
  let inner = {};
 
  y.forEach(v => inner[v] = 0);
  results[k] = inner;
});

console.log(results);
```